# TypeScript Lerna/MonoRepo Webpack development speed/optimization

Tags: typescript, webpack, lerna, monorepo

When using lerna for a TypeScript project with webpack, I'm trying to optimize the webpack speed when a development change occurs in the library.  Right now, it's taking 1m+ to recompile when code in the library changes.

Directory structure:

```
lerna.json
packages/main-project/webpack.config.js
packages/main-project/node_modules/library   (<--symlink via lerna)
packages/library/webpack.config.js
```

When you run `lerna run dev --parallel` in the root directory, it fires up webpack in parallel on both `main-project` and `library`.  With the default setup, here's what happens:

- `library` webpack compiles in about 7-8s
- `main-project` webpack recompiles the `packages/main-project/node_modules/library/dist/index.js` file into library.[hash].js in about 1m+ or so
- HMR reloads the web page

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Simply include the `library/dist/index.js` (either via `node_modules/library` or `../library` paths)
2. HMR reloads when that path changes

What I need help with is:

- How to tell `main-project/webpack.config.js` to ignore `node_modules/library` and not recompile when the library changes
- Have the main-project import the `library/dist/index.js` that was built
- Making sure HMR detects when the library changes

The config below *almost* works. All it's missing is the HRM reload if `library/dist/index.js` changes:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        name: "development",
        devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
        entry: {
            'index': './src/index.tsx',
            'style': './src/scss/themes/default.scss',
            'library': ['../library/dist/index.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /node_modules[\/\\]\\?(library).+\.js$/,
                    enforce: "pre",
                    use: ["source-map-loader"],
                }, {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader:  "ts-loader",
                            options: {
                                transpileOnly:        true,
                                experimentalWatchApi: true,
                            },
                        }
                    ],
                }, {
                    test: /library[\/\\]dist[\/\\]$/,
                    use: ['file-loader']
                }
            ],
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: false,
            removeAvailableModules: false,
            removeEmptyChunks: false,
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    "library": {
                        name: "library",
                        test: /..[\/\\]library/,
                        priority: 10,
                    },
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        test: /node_modules[\/\\](?!(library))/,
                        priority: 20,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
        },
        plugins: [],
        resolve: {
            symlinks: false,
            modules:[path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
            alias: {
                'library': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/library'),
            }
        },
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 3000,
            ignored : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/library'),
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: were you able to figure out a way to have Webpack detect when the library changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this repo for some inspiration https://github.com/dan-kez/lerna-webpack-example

As a project gets large I'd consider using babel for hot reloading in dev via the `@babel/typescript` plugin. This allows to develop quickly without needing to wait on type correctness.

If you have CI then you can enforce type correctness there. Basically use typescript to check the types but not transpile.

An alternative is to use typescript's `references` feature ([see docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)) to build each package separately and intelligently cache the result. This allows you to only build what is necessary after a change.